# R problem with apply + rbind

Tags: file-io, r

I cannot seem to get the following to work

```
directory <- "./"
files.15x16 <- c("15x16-70d.out", "15x16-71d.out")
data.15x16<-rbind( lapply( as.array(paste(directory, files.15x16, sep="")), FUN=read.csv, sep=" ", header=F) )
```

What it **should** be doing is pretty straightforward - I have a directory name, some file names, and actual files of data.  I paste the directory and file names together, read the data from the files in, and then rbind them all together into a single chunk of data.

Except the result of the lapply has the data in `[[]]` - i.e., accessing it occurs via `a[[1]], a[[2]],` etc which `rbind` doesn't seem to accept.

Suggestions?

Comment: Take a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104483/how-to-read-table-multiple-files-into-a-single-table-in-r

Comment: And some "not-exactly-the-same": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209258/merge-several-data-frames-into-one-data-frame-with-a-loop, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562124/merge-many-data-frames-from-csv-files

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `do.call`:

```
data.15x16 <-  do.call(rbind, lapply(paste(directory, files.15x16, sep=""), 
                                      FUN=read.csv, sep=" ", header=F))
```

You also don't need the `as.array` - it does not really do anything here.

Comment: brilliant, thanks; as.array was a leftover from using apply instead of lapply - apply was complaining about dim(X) not being positive