# RStudio read Created or Modified Date of file into variable

Tags: r, file, csv, date

I am using read.csv to import the data from my csv file.
I would also like to load the Created or Modified Date of the file to a new column at the end of my newly imported table.
How do I read the Created or Modified date of a file into a variable?
Thanks

Comment: Please provide a small [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) example.

Comment: Sounds like you want `file.info()`.

Comment: Kevin - You are correct file.info() is what I need.  I want to use ctime but am having an issue with syntax.  I can get file.mtime() to work correctly but when I try to get ctime file.info(??ctime??) I am not sure of the syntax.

Comment: As far as an example, I have a file MyFile="C:\myfile.csv"  Then I read it into R -- CurrentFile = read.csv(MyFile,header = F,strip.white=TRUE)  and now I want the create date of the file I just read in.

Comment: Okay, I have a solution or at least a work around.  I read in all the file info values into FileInfo.  I then extract the 'ctime' from FileInfo.   FileInfo = file.info("C:\myfile.csv)  CreateTime = format(FileInfo['ctime'],"%m/%d/%Y")  I don't know if it is right, but it works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This function may work well:

```
read.tables <- function(file.names, ...) {require(plyr)
ldply(file.names, function(fn) data.frame(read.table(fn, ...), Filename=fn, date.extraction=date(file.info(fn)$mtime)))}
```

I simply modified the function given in this topic: [how to read table multiple files into a single table in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104483/how-to-read-table-multiple-files-into-a-single-table-in-r)